# Java 8 lambda doesn't change data

Tags: lambda, java-8

Well I'm digging through Java8 lambda and I'm facing following problem - lambda doesn't change data:

DamnLambda.class:

```
public static void inc ( List<Integer> list, Funtion<Integer,Integer> func) {

    for(Integer intr : list) {
        intr = func.apply(intr);
    }
```

Let's try to invoke:

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

DamnLambda.inc(l, x -> x+=1);
System.out.println(l); //[1,2,3] ? Why not [2,3,4] ?
```

I can't understad why it doesn't change any data.
I tried also different version of same functionality:

```
l.forEach(x -> x+1); //same thing, doesn't change the data.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Assigning a value to the loop iteration variable will have no effect and, in fact, should not be done.

Comment: You're missing the point of functional programming. You're not supposed to change the input. You're supposed to generate output that is a transformation of the input.

Comment: Well guys u got me, I was blindly trying to perform some lambda operations on the list and forgotten about one of the primal rules. Btw. code compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `inc()` to:

```
public static List<Integer> inc ( List<Integer> list, Funtion<Integer,Integer> func) {

    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(Integer intr : list) {
        result.add(func.apply(intr));
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then call:

```
l = DamnLambda.inc(l, x -> x+=1);
```

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
list.replaceAll(x -> x+1);
```

Comment: It's even better than previous one, but I marked previous as an answer because he reflected the situation I had in mind. I was trying to understand usage lambda in practice.

Answer (score 4):

[Brian Goetz' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601539/1441122) is clearly the one to use if you want to mutate a list in-place. An alternative, which [alfasin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601440/1441122) seems to be describing, is to create a new list containing the modified values. The way to do with using lambda and streams is:

```
List<Integer> result =
    list.stream()
        .map(i -> i + 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: veru useful, I'm planning to go through streams today :)